# How to model an unknown amount of variables with C#

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I don't know how to explain this properly, someone please edit my title and post as needed. I thought this could be solved with polymorphism, but I couldn't get it to work. What I would like to have is as following.

I'm going to have different shapes and they all have different variables. For example, to describe a particular shape A I need:

Mandatory fields for every shape:

- starting and ending point (composed
  of 3 double variables: x, y and z)
- name (string)

A shape may or not need the following fields (maybe in the future I will need more)

- Length, width, height (all double)
- Angle
- Other variables which could be double or string

The thing is, this needs to flexible, as every shape is going to be described using XML, which I then need to load into the program. For example a cube would work like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<structure name="Cube">
    <variables>
        <point name="start" />
        <point name="end" />
        <length name="width" min="1" max="10000" unit="mm" />
        <length name="height" min="1" max="10000" unit="mm" />
    </variables>
    <points>
        <point name="topLeft">
            <x>start.x</x>
            <y>start.y - height/2</y>
            <z>start.z</z>
        </point>
        <point name="topRight">
            <x>end.x</x>
            <y>end.y - height/2</y>
            <z>end.z</z>
        </point>
        <point name="bottomLeft">
            <x>start.x</x>
            <y>start.y + height/2</y>
            <z>start.z</z>
        </point>
        <point name="bottomRight">
            <x>end.x</x>
            <y>end.y + height/2</y>
            <z>end.z</z>
        </point>
    </points>
    <connections>
        <connection type="line">
            <point name="topLeft" />
            <point name="topRight" />
            <point name="bottomRight" />
            <point name="bottomLeft" />
            <point name="topLeft" />
        </connection>
    </connections>
</structure>
```

So what I thought is, I have a base class called CVariable (with 2 abstract methods, parseString and toString), which I then inherit to make CLength (new attribute double length), CPoint (new attribute double x, y and z) and CName (new attribute string name). I can then have a class called CShape which has a list of CVariable, CPoint and CName (the connections, just a name identifying the point to be connected). The problem is, I believe, if I have a list of CVariable, I can't access the new attributes. Am I right?

Sorry if it's not clear, I will edit to add any information needed. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Quick point but it will annoy many people a lot: don't start class names with a `C` prefix.  That's a convention from MFC, pretty much.. not done in the .NET world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scheme you're thinking in is usually called a "variant". `CVariable` is not a good name for this, it's just to unspecific. But you're thinking in the right direction already. By deriving from a common base class you can pack the elements in a common container. The trick to access those derived types is using the runtime type information system: There is the `typeof` keyword telling you the actual type of the object you're referring to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/58918ffs.aspx

A word of warning: Getting into a situation where one needs a variant is often a hint, that something in the design of the data structure *may* be flawed and rethinking the problem is a good idea.

Comment: Hi datenwolf, thanks for the tips. I have made CVariable as an abstract class, and I just read about covariance. Shouldn't it be possible to have a list of CVariable? So I can then get the derived class using typeof. But I get the following error: Cannot create an instance of an abstract class. Which actually makes sense, but then I'm stuck again.

Comment: Correct, abstract classes cannot be instanciated. You need to derive from your base variant class into decendent classes (Line, Point, etc.), instanciate such and then append them to the list of CVariant **references**. It will not work with a list of CVariant itself, only with references. MSDN has an excellent example of polymorphism, which incidently actually does what you're up to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx#Y319

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you're overengineering. Why not just:

```
<cube center-x="44" center-y="-43" center-z="20" edge-length="42" />
<sphere center-x="0" center-y="1" radius="3" />
```

Then each class will be responsible for loading itself from an XML representation and serializing itself back to XML.

If, however, you need to be able to describe an arbitrary 3D-object, you need to describe individual facets and vertices.

I might be massively off, but again: I don't know all the requirements.

Comment: The thing is anton, the shapes are all 3D, but they are described as 2D (which makes it a bit more simple) and then extruded. But we may have arbritary weird shapes. That's why I need it as flexible as possible. Thanks for the idea though.